# Euler-Lagrange equation in a differential form notation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, variational-calculus, chern-simons-theory

Treating the Lagrangian density as a $d$-form in $d$-dimensional spacetime, how can one write the Euler-Lagrangian equation basis independently in the form notation? If possible, can you also apply that to the 3D Chern-Simons theory given by
$$ S = \frac{k}{4\pi} \int A \wedge dA $$
as an example?

For example, if I am given a $U(1)$ gauge field theory, the variation would be
$$δ S = \lim_{\epsilon→ 0} \frac{S(A + \epsilon \, δ A) - S(A)}{\epsilon}\label{Eq:EL eq}$$
where $\delta$ is not a derivative but means some variation.
With $\bar{A} ≡ g^{\mu\nu} A_\nu \partial_\mu$, I wonder if Eq. $\ref{Eq:EL eq}$ can be written as something like
$$ ∫ i_{\delta\bar{A}}\mathcal{L}_{\bar{A}} \mathcal{L} $$
where $i_X$ is the interior derivative along the vector field $X$, the first $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie derivative and the second $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lagrangian density.

Comment: *Treating the Lagrangian density as a -form...* Why should it be one? Are you just assuming that it is?

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks for pointing that out; I had the given action in mind and carelessly generalised this fact. Can anyone answer this with the assumption that the Lagrangian is a d-form in d-dimension?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_map#Harmonic_map_heat_flowhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator